# Saying Shema from Klaf

Tags: minhag, shema, safrus, korbanos-ketores-prayers

I've heard of saying parshat haketoret from a klaf. Does a similar practice exist for shema? If so, is it just Shema and V'haya (essentially a mezuzah) or the above and Parshat Tzitzit?

Comment: Please retag accordingly

Comment: Have you heard of such a thing,I havent

Comment: @sam, neither have I. This question originates from a discussion I had with my father the other night re saying Ketoret from klaf.

Comment: it would help if you can include that discussion because I don't see why shema is any different than any other prayer which if said on a klaf is a segualah unlike ketores which is sourced in the Kaf Hachaim